# Grant access to users on multiple tables on multiple Mysql server

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

I have a set of 50 MariaDB servers that have the same table names in all the databases. Database names and table names are all the same. How can I grant access to the same users on all 50 database tables? I have an ssh key set up on all the servers and do not want to log on to individual servers to grant access.

Comment: are all user on the 50 MariaDB server has the same grants for users and ips ?

Comment: If the servers do not have replication between them, you could certainly write a script that connects to each server and creates the user accounts and grants the proper privileges. If you update schema with migrations, you could also use a migration to define all the user accounts and privileges.

Comment: Use [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html#parameter-priv) with the appropriate modules and configuration. Its a not too steep a learning curve and with 50 servers you'll need this functionality more than once.

Comment: Yes, all the grants are the same but the IP are different for different servers.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you have an SSH key already setup, so you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

servers="server1
server2
server3"

for server in $servers
do
    ssh user@"$server" <YOUR COMMAND HERE>
done
```

Replace "YOUR COMMAND HERE" with your MariaDB command(s).

If you have many other things to run on all those servers, `Ansible` is the way to go.